# How to find data for last 20 tuesdays

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-date-functions

I want to find data for the last 20 Tuesday.

```
        Date                    value
2020-03-03 01:12:15               5
2020-02-25 07:12:15               13
2020-02-24 08:12:15               1
2020-02-23 09:12:15               32
2020-02-22 10:12:15               7
2020-02-21 11:12:15               43
2020-02-20 12:12:15               7
2020-02-19 13:12:15               1
2020-02-18 14:12:15               31
2020-02-17 15:12:15               14
```

and so one

My desired output is

```
        Date                    value
2020-03-03 01:12:15               5
2020-02-25 07:12:15               13
2020-02-18 14:12:15               31
```

and so on

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Last 20 Tuesdays? With and without values? (I.e. any Tuesday from the last 20 * 7 + 6 dates?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from t
where weekday(date) = 2
order by date desc
limit 3  -- or 20
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query

```
select t.*
from t
where weekday(date) = 2
order by date desc
limit 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use year and dayofweek

```
select  * from  myTable  
where year(date) = 2020
and dayofweek(date) = 5
```